# Unable to set height of NSButton

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsbutton

I have some NSButtons of style Round Textured inserted into an NSToolbar.

I have created some custom images for the buttons and would like to make them vertically bigger, however the height field for the button is greyed out.

Anyone got any ideas why, and if there is a way around it?

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From NSButtonCell Class Reference

> **NSTexturedRoundedBezelStyle** The height of this button is fixed.

[image]

You can use `NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle` Bezel Styles

[image]

Comment: Boom, that's exactly it, doh! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to uncheck Bordered in the latest version of XCode

[image]

Comment: I did that, but then the background color of the button becomes transparent.